# Форма регистрации не проходит валидацию is_valid()

Tags: python, django

Пишу бэкенд на django, сделал кастомную форму регистрации.

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                       'placeholder': 'Enter your email'}))
phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                      'placeholder': 'Enter your phone number'}))
country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder': 'Enter your country'}))
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                             'placeholder': 'Enter your password'}))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email','phone', 'country', 'password')
```

Так же написал обработку регистрации:

```
        if reg_form.is_valid():
            reg_form.save()
            email = request.POST['email']
            print(f'{email} зарегистрирован!')
            password = request.POST['password']
            print(f'Авторизация {email} ...')
            user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                auth.login(request, user)
                print(f'{email} Авторизован!')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            pass

context = {'login_form': login_form,
           'reg_form': reg_form}
return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

Форма не проходит проверку is_valid().
Подскажите, как пофиксить?